# modules in verilog?

Tags: verilog, xilinx

In my recent project in Xilinx ISE, I need to create two modules, one for 4-bit multiplier and other for 4-bit adder.

In between i need to call the 4-bit adder in multiplier module which I am doing by calling adder:

```
module multiplier(inputs ..., output ...) begin

always @(posedge clk) begin

    shift_product[23:16]=16'b1;

    twentyfourbit_adder(sum,shift_product,sum,cout);

end
```

I didn't write the whole code because I am just asking that is this correct method to use one module in other.

Comment: In general you instantiate one module inside another.  Without seeing more code it's difficult to tell what's going on there, but it looks like you are instantiating modules within the always block, which is very probably not what you want to be doing.  What you probably want to do is have the combinational module (24 bit adder) instantiated outside of the always block and modify the input shift_product within the always block.  You also probably want to be using the nonblocking <= and not = in the always block.

Comment: I think part of the problem might be that you're thinking about "calling" a module when in fact you should be thinking about "instantiating" the module.

Comment: Forget *everything* you know about procedural programming. We are talking HDL now.

Comment: Module instantiations should not go inside an always block. Stuff feeding them (anything of ```reg``` or ```integer```) should be driven by an always block. Then you simply feed that signal into the module instantiation. The always block is not saying "this should always be here" (a module instantiation is), it is saying "always when anything on the sensitivity list (bit in brackets) occurs, do something".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Verilog, when you are **instantiating** a module, that means you are adding extra **hardware** to the board.

This hardware **must be** added **before simulation starts**(i.e. at compile time). Here, you can **not** add/remove hardware at each clock pulse.

Once instantiated, the module is executed/checked for **each timestamp** of simulation, till the end.

So to execute any module, just instantiate it, providing the clk and other required inputs to it, and **add the always block in the sub-module itself**.

Once the hardware is *instantiated*, it shall be executed according to the logic inside it, for *entire life time*.

One more comment, instantiation of module requires an **instance name**, to uniquely identify all the pieces of hardware. So for `twentyfourbit_adder`, use any instance name like `twentyfourbit_adder ta(sum,shift_product,sum,cout);`

Your code may go as follows:

```
module multiplier(inputs ..., output ...) begin

// Instantiate just once
twentyfourbit_adder ta(sum,shift_product,sum,cout);

always @(posedge clk) begin

    shift_product[23:16]=16'b1;
   // Other stuff here...    
end
```

**Side Note:**

You may have mixed the understanding about **module instantiation** and calling of **task/function**. Module is a **static** entity while task/function can be **dynamic** ones. As you showed, *if twentyfourbit_adder* is a task, then the above call is valid.

I have added most of my answer from previous answer to this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33719071/error-while-using-always-block-in-verilog/33719290). For more information, refer to [Module Instantiation](http://verilog.renerta.com/mobile/source/vrg00027.htm) and  [Instantiating Modules and Primitives](http://support.ema-eda.com/search/eslfiles/default/main/sl_legacy_releaseinfo/staging/sl3/release_info/psd142/veriaref/chap10.html) links.